# hide property of a push

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, object

I have added property in a push function to hide the label and show the input but when the user clicks on Save changes I want to do the opposite i.e hide the input and show the label. I am using `ng-hide`

```
  <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
    <td>
        <label ng-hide="personalDetail.lab" for="settings"> {{personalDetail.Sname}}</label>
        <input ng-show="personalDetail.lab" type="text" ng-model="personalDetail.Sname" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label ng-hide="personalDetail.lab" data-val="{{personalDetail.Settings}}" for="desc">{{personalDetail.Settings}}</label>
        <input style="display:none" data-val="{{personalDetail.Settings}}" ng-model="personalDetail.Settings" type="text" value="{{personalDetail.Settings}}" />
        <input ng-show="personalDetail.lab" ng-model="personalDetail.Settings" type="text" value="{{personalDetail.Settings}}" />
    </td>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-space" ng-click="save()" value="Save Changes" />
```

```js
$scope.addNew = function () {
  $scope.personalDetails.push({
    'Sname': "",
    'Settings': "",
    'lab' : true 
  });

  $scope.save = function () {
    $scope.personalDetails.lab = false;
  }
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions properly. This was an unreadable mess to start with

Comment: Is the input for save  inside the ng-repeat?

Comment: no its outside i just showed it here

Comment: lab is true i want to make it false just when user clicks on save changes to hide the input and show the label

Comment: @Aftabkhan Do you want to change the `lab` property for all the details objects?

Comment: @Aftabkhan Why did you remove the check against my answer?

Comment: @Vivz: he didn't. Your answer still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$scope.personalDetails` is an array, you have to access each property using the index. So loop through the array and change the lab property.

```
  $scope.save = function () {
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.personalDetails.length;i++)
     $scope.personalDetails[i].lab = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `save` button is outside of the `ng-repeat` and you want to change the `lab` property of all the array elements, you just need to use a `map` over the `personalDetails` array like this:

```
$scope.save = function() {
  $scope.personalDetails = $scope.personalDetails.map(function(detail) {
    detail.lab = false;
    return detail;
  });
}
```

This will update all the `personalDetails` objects.